# how to redirect all sub domain into http instead of https except the main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, https, subdomain

Today I just bought SSL certificate from my single domain and it works fine as **mydomain.com**, but when I select sub domain example **city.mydomain.com** its not working all page's are look totally different, all my CSS file look very poor, malfunction on page layout. any help with appropriate example will be highly appreciated.

I have more than 70 sub domain

Main domain should be like this >>> https://www.presskr.com
and all sub domain should be like this https://subdomain.presskr.com

Comment: What do you want to redirect to what ? you want to redirect http:// example.com to https:// example.com and https:// everythingelse.example.com to http:// everythingelse.example.com ?

Comment: I want to redirect **https//:emaple.com** & sub domain **http:// area.eample.com** because i have single domain SSL certificate

Answer (score 1):

Write below rules in your root htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: still not working on said command                                                            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Answer (score 0):

this will also work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http://www
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how to redirect all sub domain into http cloud you please send me redirection method with easy example, should i need to redirect via **cPanel**? if yes then how to do, i am beginner i do not have much knowledge about coding

Comment: just remove all redirection related code and then past the above code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect **everything** to https if I understand. And the page looks strange.

It's a mixed content problem, you need to edit your webpage to change the links of javascript, css and others ressources from http to https.

You can't solve that problem only with a redirect because when the browser see he need to fetch the http js/css/* for the https webpage, he stop because it's insecure. He stops before making the request so the browser is not aware of your redirect.

A temporary fix is to use https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/ but it's not working everywhere http://caniuse.com/#feat=upgradeinsecurerequests